# Xamarin Service Notification Won't Start

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service

I have the below code for sending a notification, but i don't see the notification sent when I start my application.  Am i missing something?

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{

    const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 9000;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        // Code omitted for clarity - here is where the service would do something.

        // Work has finished, now dispatch anotification to let the user know.
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
           // .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification_small_icon)
           // .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_content_title))
           .SetContentTitle("Comic Pull App")
            //.SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_content_text));
            .SetContentText("New Comics came out this week. Repull this month if needed.");
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

I have the below in my `MainActivity` :

```
StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));
```

I have the below in my manifest file :

```
<application android:label="ToolbarFun" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
  <service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="false"  android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i don't see the notification sent when I start my application. Am i missing something?

You can't do that without using `SetSmallIcon()` method. You have to set an icon for `Notification`, only then  the `Notification` can be sent.

Comment: @Freiza1991, is there any problem?

Comment: Yep that was the problem! Thanks a lot for the help. I just added an icon and it kicked off.